# How can we inject page props in Next.JS?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I would like to for example use the React Context API to pass props to pages from the _app file.

Another use case would be to refactor a ReactJS routing, where state is passed from the app.js to pages through the route definition like so :

`<Route><Component state=state/></Route>`

I found [this documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app) but it feels like we should not touch the `pageProps`  as it only for staticly generated props.

Here is a concrete piece of code I am trying to fix:

```js
const App = (Component,pageProps) => {
  const [mobileOpen, setMobileOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [cart, setCart] = useState({});
  const [order, setOrder] = useState({});
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

  const fetchProducts = async () => {
    const { data } = await commerce.products.list();

    setProducts(data);
  };

  const fetchCart = async () => {
    setCart(await commerce.cart.retrieve());
  };

  const handleAddToCart = async (productId, quantity) => {
    const item = await commerce.cart.add(productId, quantity);

    setCart(item.cart);
  };

  const handleUpdateCartQty = async (lineItemId, quantity) => {
    const response = await commerce.cart.update(lineItemId, { quantity });

    setCart(response.cart);
  };

  const handleRemoveFromCart = async (lineItemId) => {
    const response = await commerce.cart.remove(lineItemId);

    setCart(response.cart);
  };

  const handleEmptyCart = async () => {
    const response = await commerce.cart.empty();

    setCart(response.cart);
  };

  const refreshCart = async () => {
    const newCart = await commerce.cart.refresh();

    setCart(newCart);
  };

  const handleCaptureCheckout = async (checkoutTokenId, newOrder) => {
    try {
      const incomingOrder = await commerce.checkout.capture(checkoutTokenId, newOrder);

      setOrder(incomingOrder);

      refreshCart();
    } catch (error) {
      setErrorMessage(error.data.error.message);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProducts();
    fetchCart();
  }, []);

  const handleDrawerToggle = () => setMobileOpen(!mobileOpen);

/* switch (useRouter.pathname) {
  case ('/shop'):return <Products products={products} onAddToCart={handleAddToCart} handleUpdateCartQty />
  case ('/cart'): return<Cart cart={cart} onUpdateCartQty={handleUpdateCartQty} onRemoveFromCart={handleRemoveFromCart} onEmptyCart={handleEmptyCart} />
  case ('/checkout'):    return    <Checkout cart={cart} order={order} onCaptureCheckout={handleCaptureCheckout} error={errorMessage} />
}
 */

  return <Component className="App" {...pageProps} />
}
export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a switch statement instead of the routing system will do:

In your example:

```js
import {useRouter} from 'next/router'
[...]
switch (router.pathname) {
    case "/shop":
      return (
        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
          <CssBaseline />
          <Navbar
            totalItems={cart.total_items}
            handleDrawerToggle={handleDrawerToggle}
          />

          <Products
            products={products}
            onAddToCart={handleAddToCart}
            handleUpdateCartQty
          />
        </div>
      );
    case "/cart":
      return (
        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
          <CssBaseline />
          <Navbar
            totalItems={cart.total_items}
            handleDrawerToggle={handleDrawerToggle}
          />

          <Cart
            cart={cart}
            onUpdateCartQty={handleUpdateCartQty}
            onRemoveFromCart={handleRemoveFromCart}
            onEmptyCart={handleEmptyCart}
          />
        </div>
      );
    case "/checkout":
      return (
        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
          <CssBaseline />
          <Navbar
            totalItems={cart.total_items}
            handleDrawerToggle={handleDrawerToggle}
          />

          <Checkout
            cart={cart}
            order={order}
            onCaptureCheckout={handleCaptureCheckout}
            error={errorMessage}
          />
        </div>
      );
  }
```

Comment: This is not a good idea because switching routes seems to be impossible because 'route not found error'